# How to add a user function to a jrxml that is compiled from JasperCompilerManager

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Report in a Java project where I have a JRXML file and in a specific class, I compile the file and then fill it with the data. But now, I want to create a function that returns the value of the result of a sum of integers but in letters.

I tried using iReport and creating a JAR file and it works from de IDE of Jasper on the preview but I'm working over a spring-boot project on IntelliJ IDE and I don't have an idea of how to replicate in this another environment where I compile the JRXML from code using JasperCompilerManager.

In the file `sr_front_kardex_1.jrxml` is where i want to add the function like:

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement x="240" y="95" width="100" height="30" uuid="e531b6f4-146b-4b62-b613-3122554c6d01"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[NumToWord.convert(1)]]</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The code in NumToWord.java file is:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class NumToWord {

    public static String convert(Integer anioscursados){
        Map<Integer,String> mapGradosText = new HashMap<>();
        mapGradosText.put(1,"UN AÑO");
        mapGradosText.put(2,"DOS AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(3,"TRES AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(4,"CUATRO AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(5,"CINCO AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(6,"SEIS AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(7,"SIETE AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(8,"OCHO AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(9,"NUEVE AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(10,"DIEZ AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(11,"ONCE AÑOS");
        mapGradosText.put(12,"DOCE AÑOS");

        return mapGradosText.containsKey(anioscursados) ? mapGradosText.get(anioscursados) : "-" ;
    }
}
```

The part where I compile the JRXML is in the next code:

```java
System.out.println(NumToWord.convert(1)); //print UN AÑO
String path = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + mainReport).getURI().getPath();
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);

String pathSr = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + subReport).getURI().getPath();
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(pathSr);

String pathSrb = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:sr_front_kardex_1.jrxml").getURI().getPath();
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(pathSrb);

jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<String,Object>(),new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lsDataSource));
```

And this is the error that appears.

```
error en ReporteCajaManagerImpl net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. NumToWord cannot be resolved
                value = NumToWord.convert(1); //$JR_EXPR_ID=36$
                        <------->
2. NumToWord cannot be resolved
                value = NumToWord.convert(1); //$JR_EXPR_ID=36$
                        <------->
3. NumToWord cannot be resolved
                value = NumToWord.convert(1); //$JR_EXPR_ID=36$
                        <------->
3 errors
```

I'm sure that it's because the JAR file it's not included but I don't know how to do this.

The directory tree looks like:

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

According to the people that help me in the comments and the answer of one of them (Oscar Perez and Petter Friberg) I put the class in the project (as shown in the picture above where I display the directory tree) and I wrote the absolute path of the class on the jrxml file like the following example:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[org.eduadvent.reportes.NumToWord.convert(1)]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: `NumToWord` needs to be in your runtime classpath.

Comment: How can I do this? I see a `.classpath ` file in the root directory. It's in that file?

Comment: Is `NumToWord` in your IntelliJ project? If so, what is the absolute classname?

Comment: No, I create that class on Netbeans and the absolute classname is NumToWord. In that file that I mentioned before I have the following line: `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Soporte3/Documents/NetBeansProjects/NumToWord/dist/NumToWord.jar"/>`

Comment: Would it be possible to add this class to your project directly? Not the jar but the .java and compile it alltogether?

Comment: But how can the jrxml know the function? I'll try

Comment: When you compile the JRXML it becomes a Java class that exists in your classpath, so it has access to all the classpath resources (including other classes).

Comment: The error still appears. I put the file in the same directory of the jrxml as you can see in the picture that I just added above.

Comment: `.java` files must be inside `/main/java` directory, not `/resources`.

Comment: I try that too. I updated the picture above. I tried importing the class inside the class where the jrxml is compiled and nothing :( the class where I compile the report is `GeneraKardexManagerImpl`

Comment: What is the absolute name of the class where you compile your report? Could you try to access to `NumToWord` directly from this code?

Comment: Yes, I do. I print the result of `NumToWord.convert(1)` a few lines before compiling the report and it displays the correct result right before showing the errors. I updated the code above to show you. The absolute name of the class is `GeneraKardexManagerImpl.java`.

Comment: set the full name with package es. `com.my.package.NumToWord.convert(1)` and just add it to classpath, you can also use import statement in jrxml if you don't want to specify full name.

Comment: @PetterFriberg on the jrxml file or where?

Comment: what is the name of the package for the class NumToWord?

Comment: No! According to your screenshot the absolute name is not `GeneraKardexManagerImpl` but `org.eduadvent.reportes.managerImpl.krdes.GeneraKardexManagerImpl`!

Comment: It works! :D Thank you both, love you <3

Comment: I guess you are just missing specifying package name either directly  `com.my.package.NumToWord.convert(1)` or via import in jrxml example `<import value="com.my.package.NumToWord"/>`

Comment: Glad to have helped you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling a JRXML converts it in a regular java class that lives in your classpath. So it has access to all your classpath objects.

To access to a member function you just need to specify it's absolute name inside of your report. So:

1. Ensure your `NumToWork` class lives inside your source classpath.
2. Change your JRXML to reference this class absolutely:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[org.eduadvent.reportes.NumToWord.convert(1)]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: or import it in jrxml `<import value="org.eduadvent.reportes.NumToWord"/>`